React / Flask application guide: Authentication not working
I'm trying to follow this guide to implement authentication for a React-based app against a Python/Flask-based API. Everything seems to work except when I get to the heading 'Make an authenticated call'. Clicking the page 'Secret' when logged in, yields the following error:
Access token can not be extracted. Either whole 'session' must be a string (access token only) or 'getAccessToken' function should be provided
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/utils/extractAccessToken.js/exports.extractAccessToken@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41742:11
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/exports.createAuthProvider/getSession/</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40660:48
step@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40594:17
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/__generator</verb/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40543:14
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/__awaiter</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40517:67
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/__awaiter<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40499:10
getSession@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40655:12
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/exports.createAuthProvider/authFetch</</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40680:34
step@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40594:17
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/__generator</verb/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40543:14
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/__awaiter</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40517:67
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/__awaiter<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40499:10
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/createAuthProvider.js/exports.createAuthProvider/authFetch<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40674:12
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/utils/createAuthFetch.js/exports.createAuthFetch/</</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41511:34
step@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41486:17
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/utils/createAuthFetch.js/__generator</verb/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41435:14
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/utils/createAuthFetch.js/__awaiter</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41409:67
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/utils/createAuthFetch.js/__awaiter<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41391:10
./node_modules/react-token-auth/lib/utils/createAuthFetch.js/exports.createAuthFetch/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41506:12
./src/App.js/Secret/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:261:53
commitHookEffectListMount@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30730:30
commitPassiveMountOnFiber@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32223:42
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32195:38
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32185:45
commitPassiveMountEffects@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32175:38
flushPassiveEffectsImpl@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34058:32
flushPassiveEffects@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34011:18
commitRootImpl@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33970:9
commitRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33753:23
performSyncWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33262:17
flushSyncCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21237:26
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js/ensureRootIsScheduled/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32867:17

The source code for App.js is shown below:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
// import {login, useAuth, logout} from "./auth"
import {login, authFetch, useAuth, logout} from "./auth"

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/secret">Secret</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/secret" element={<Secret />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api").then(resp => resp.json()).then(resp => console.log(resp))
  }, [])
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function Login() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const onSubmitClick = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("You pressed login")
    let opts = {
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    }
    console.log(opts)
    fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(opts)
    }).then(r => r.json())
      .then(token => {
        if (token.access_token){
          console.log(token)          
        }
        else {
          console.log("Please type in correct username/password")
        }
      })
  }

  const handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value)
  }

  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value)
  }

  // const [logged] = useAuth();
  let [logged, session] = useAuth();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      {!logged? <form action="#">
        <div>
          <input type="text" 
            placeholder="Username" 
            onChange={handleUsernameChange}
            value={username} 
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={handlePasswordChange}
            value={password}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={onSubmitClick} type="submit">
          Login Now
        </button>
      </form>
      : <button onClick={() => logout()}>Logout</button>}
    </div>
  
  )
}

function Secret() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    
    // const f = await authFetch('/api/protected');
    authFetch("/api/protected").then(response => {
      if (response.status === 401){
        setMessage("Sorry you aren't authorized!")
        return null
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then(response => {
      if (response && response.message){
        setMessage(response.message)
      }
    })  
  }, [])
  return (
    <h2>Secret: {message}</h2>
  )
}

What am I doing wrong? Should I consider a different approach to adding authentication to a React / Flask-based app? All the guides on this seem awfully complicated and complex.
